# How to go from root mean squared error to percentage accuracy in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm creating a linear regression model. To test the accuracy I have seen tutorials that calculate RMSE, but I don't know how to go from there to reporting a percentage for the accuracy of my model. Like say this model predicts with 86% accuracy. I've seen a lot of publications report their accuracy this way.

Comment: Accuracy is a slippery concept when talking about linear regression. There is no result from a linear regression called "accuracy". It's easy to talk about accuracy with a categorical classification model, and this is the kind of model that I often see reported as accuracy: "This model can predict how you will vote with 86% accuracy". But saying that a model can predict the height of a tree with 86% accuracy is problematic. What does that mean? An 86% chance of getting the height exactly right? Being 100% certain of being within 14% of the true height? What measure are you looking for?

Comment: @AllanCameron I'm looking for an acceptable and common way to report the accuracy of the model. So is it OK to just report the RMSE and giving the mean and maximum of the output data? Is that common practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a linear regression model `lmMod` and test data `test_data`, we can find the predictions that the linear model produces by doing the following.

```
predicted_values_lm <- predict(lmMod, test_data)
```

Now lets create a dataframe with the predictions and the real test values.

```
prediction_frame <- data.frame(cbind(actual_values = test_data$values, predicted_values = predicted_values_lm ))
```

And with this dataframe, we can now calculate [Min/Max Accuracy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/287143/meaning-of-min-max-accuracy-of-a-regression-model).

```
min_max_accuracy <- mean(apply(prediction_frame, 1, min) / apply(prediction_frame, 1, max))
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this OK to divide this RMSE by the mean of output variable in my test data?

Comment: @Parnian I'm confused by your question.  Why would you do that? What are you trying to show? Normalizing RMSE by the mean output vale based on your test data does not seem like a meaningful quantity.

Comment: The reason why I'm trying to convert RMSE to something like percentage is to be able to explain it to other, say patients, that for example with the radiological characteristics of your tumor, it is 86% possible to excise 80% of your tumor. But giving RMSE to a patient doesn't make much sense to them.

Comment: I do it also often. What I do is to 100 - (100*rmse/gt.mean()). BUT I deal with negative values which means a very bad prediction in my context. It's ok but sometimes it's better to say that the precision is 0 when it's too bad. While you never use this precision to calculate anything else, there is no problem.